# Why "r" for vector-valued functions?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Why is the letter **r** typically used to describe vector-valued functions, like $r(t)$ or sometimes $R(t)$? Is it short for something like vecto**r**?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with "radius"? I'm not sure what the connection would be, though.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I also thought about radius. If the fixed endpoint of the vector r is taken to be the center of curvature of the trajectory traced by the moving endpoint of r then the length of r is just the radius of curvature. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Well, usually you can represent **position** with a vector valued function, that starts with a $p$, and mathematicians like more edgy symbols, so we use the closest one, hence $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from the Latin *radius*, meaning 'rod' in this context ([source](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/radius)). As a word, it conveys the idea that another shape is being traced by a straight line.

As a word of advice, don't always try to find a logical reason behind terminology and notation. Language, unfortunately unlike mathematics, rarely pays much attention to detail.

Comment: A ray has an initial point, presumably the origin, and continues indefinitely, so how does that make sense considering vector-valued functions must have a terminal point for the position?

Comment: It sometimes meant staff, or rod ([source](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/radius)). It contains the idea that a straight line traces another shape.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @totembowl That was a mistake on my part. *Radius* does mean both 'ray' and 'rod', but I forgot that it meant the latter when I first replied.

Comment: @MarcPaul My only source of the "idea that a straight line traces another shape" is a maths historian who taught me at university. He did various translations of papers which were originally written in Latin.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out searching for **radius vector** on Wikipedia redirects to [position vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_%28vector%29). There, the page says "a **position vector** is also called a **location vector** or a **radius vector**." So, **r** is indeed for radius.

Note that I'm posting this answer in the hope the link to Wikipedia will provide some credibility rather than sounding like an opinion.